# Packer user_data_file on on AWS without <powershell>

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, packer

I use packer to build Windows VM image on AWS,

To setup WinRM I want to use "official" `ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1` script

But if I put it to Packer's `user_data_file` I doesn't work

It works only if I add manually `<powershell>...</powershell>` to the first and last lines of `ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1` script which is not convenient (I'd prefer to refer to the latest `ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1` maintained by Ansible guys)

Any ideas how to get rid of `<powershell>...</powershell>` lines?

Comment: This is a limitation of AWS and Windows. While you can specify powershell as the type of provisioner in Packer and avoid specifying `<powershell>` in the script, for `user_data` this kind of capability to specify shell interpreter external to the script does not exist.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I feel like that comment should be an answer